# Program crashes the moment I start typing in the search bar

Tags: java, android, sql, android-sqlite

When I run the program, everything looks fine but the moment I type a letter in the search bar, the program crashes immediately.It mostly shows Exceptions at `searchBar()` function in LibraryDbAdapter class and at `onQueryTextChange(String newText)` in `SearchViewActivity` class.I am using `ListView` too.

**LibraryDbAdapter.java**

```
 package com.example.waheed.library;

 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.SQLException;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
 import android.util.Log;

 /**
 * Created by Waheed on 6/30/17.
  */

public class LibraryDbAdapter {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "rowid";
//public static final String KEY_LIBRARY = "library";
public static final String KEY_BOOKNAME = "bookname";
public static final String KEY_BOOKAUTHOR = "bookauthor";
public static final String KEY_STORENAME = "storename";
public static final String KEY_STOREADDRESS = "storeaddress";
public static final String KEY_STORELAT = "storelat";
public static final String KEY_STORELONG = "storelong";
public static final String KEY_SEARCH = "searchData";

private static final String TAG = "LibraryDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LibraryData";
private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "LibraryInfo";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


//Create a FTS3 Virtual Table for fast searches
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " USING fts3(" +
               // KEY_LIBRARY + "," +
                KEY_BOOKNAME + "," +
                KEY_BOOKAUTHOR + "," +
                KEY_STORENAME + "," +
                KEY_STOREADDRESS + "," +
                KEY_STORELAT + "," +
                KEY_STORELONG + "," +
                KEY_SEARCH + "," +
                " UNIQUE (" + KEY_BOOKNAME + "));";


private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public LibraryDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public LibraryDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

public long createLibrary( String bookname, String bookauthor, String storename, String storeaddress, String storelat, String storelong) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    String searchValue = bookname;

    //initialValues.put(KEY_LIBRARY, library);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BOOKNAME, bookname);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BOOKAUTHOR, bookauthor);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STORENAME, storename);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STOREADDRESS, storeaddress);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STORELAT, storelat);
    initialValues.put(KEY_STORELONG, storelong);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SEARCH, searchValue);

    return mDb.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public Cursor searchBook(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    String query = "SELECT " +

            KEY_BOOKNAME +

            " from " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
            " where " + KEY_SEARCH + " MATCH '" + inputText + "';";
    Log.w(TAG, query);
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

public boolean deleteAllLibrary() {

    int doneDelete = 0;
    doneDelete = mDb.delete(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, null);
    Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
    return doneDelete > 0;

}


}
```

**SearchViewActivity.java**

```
package com.example.waheed.library;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class SearchViewActivity extends Activity implements 
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
    SearchView.OnCloseListener {

private ListView mListView;
private SearchView searchView;
private LibraryDbAdapter mDbHelper;

private TextView inspectionDate;
private TextView bookName;
private TextView bookAuthor;
private TextView storeName;
private TextView storeAddress;
private TextView storeLat;
private TextView storeLong;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    inspectionDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inspectionDate);
    displayDate();

    mDbHelper = new LibraryDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    //Clean all Customers
    mDbHelper.deleteAllLibrary();
    //Add some Customer data as a sample
    mDbHelper.createLibrary("How to Win Friends and Influence People", "Dale Carnegie", "Book Centre", " Haider Rd, Rawalpindi 46000", "33.596651", "73.049094");
    mDbHelper.createLibrary("The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People", "Stephen Covey", "Idris Book Bank", "Bank Rd, Rawalpindi 46000", "33.595789", "73.052405");
    mDbHelper.createLibrary("Think and Grow Rich", "Napoleon Hill", "Students Book Company", "Bank Rd, Rawalpindi 44000", "33.596524", "73.051051");
    mDbHelper.createLibrary("Psycho-Cybernetics", "Maxwell Maltz", "Old Book Bank", "Green Super Market, Kashmir Rd, Saddar, Rawalpindi, Punjab", "33.595810", "73.051530");
    mDbHelper.createLibrary("How to stop worrying and start living", "Dale Carnegie", "Saeed Book Bank", "F-, Street 7, Islamabad 44000", "33.722446", "73.058763");
    mDbHelper.createLibrary("A New Earth", " Eckhart Tolle", "Variety Books", "41-BC, Bank Rd, Saddar, Rawalpindi 46000", "33.597497", "73.049917");
    mDbHelper.createLibrary("Blink: The Power of Thinking Without Thinking", "Malcolm Gladwell", "Rehan Book Shop", "Islamabad", "33.689734", "73.031652");
    mDbHelper.createLibrary("First Things First", "Stephen Covey", "Idris Book Bank", "Bank Rd, Rawalpindi 46000", "33.595789", "73.052405");
    mDbHelper.createLibrary("Emotional Intelligence", "Daniel Goleman", "Book Centre", " Haider Rd, Rawalpindi 46000", "33.596651", "73.049094");
    mDbHelper.createLibrary("Anatomy of the Spirit", "Caroline Myss", "Students Book Company", "Bank Rd, Rawalpindi 44000", "33.596524", "73.051051");

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mDbHelper  != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    showResults(newText + "*");
    return false;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    showResults(query + "*");
    return false;
}

public boolean onClose() {
    showResults("");
    return false;
}

private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.searchBook((query != null ? query.toString() : "@@@@"));

    if (cursor == null) {
        //
    } else {
        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[]{
                LibraryDbAdapter.KEY_BOOKNAME,
                LibraryDbAdapter.KEY_BOOKAUTHOR,
                LibraryDbAdapter.KEY_STORENAME,
                LibraryDbAdapter.KEY_STOREADDRESS,
                LibraryDbAdapter.KEY_STORELAT,
                LibraryDbAdapter.KEY_STORELONG
        };

        // Specify the Corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
        int[] to = new int[] {     R.id.sbook,
                R.id.sauthor,
                R.id.sstore,
                R.id.sstoreaddress,
                R.id.slat,
                R.id.slong};

        // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter books = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.bookresult, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(books);

        // Define the on-click listener for the list items
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
                String Book = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Book"));
                String Author = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Author"));
                String Store = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Store"));
                String storeaddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("storeaddress"));
                String lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("lat"));
                String lon = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("lon"));

                //Check if the Layout already exists
                LinearLayout bookLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.booklayout);
                if(bookLayout == null){
                    //Inflate the Customer Information View
                    LinearLayout leftLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rightLayout);
                    View bookInfo = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bookinfo, leftLayout, false);
                    leftLayout.addView(bookInfo);
                }

                //Get References to the TextViews
                bookName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.book);
                bookAuthor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.author);
                storeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.store);
                storeAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.storeaddress);
                storeLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
                storeLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);

                // Update the parent class's TextView
                bookName.setText(Book);
                bookAuthor.setText(Author);
                storeName.setText(Store);
                storeAddress.setText(storeaddress);
                storeLat.setText(lat);
                storeLong.setText(lon);

                searchView.setQuery("",true);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void displayDate() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    inspectionDate.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("/")
                    .append(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("/")
                    .append(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));
}
}
```

Comment: can you share the crash logs?

Comment: Please share your crash logs. And there is no searchBar() function?

Comment: Oh sorry.I meant searchBook().And there are too many crash logs.

Comment: We would help you faster if you gave us the error in the crash log, try to filter by Log Level : Error in the logcat or try filtering by your package name

Comment: Here is a link to my image which shows the crash logs.
https://scontent-mxp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/19576842_1815847702039514_1539622963_o.png?oh=db0411118429a0ac5193b1b33850fb52&oe=595845FF